# React NativeのTextinputやNative BaseのInputコンポーネントをTextコンポーネントの中で使いたい

Tags: react-native

あるアプリをReact NativeとNative Baseを用いて開発しようとしており、
以下のような空欄補充問題を実装したいと考えています。

[image: I want to implement questions like this.]

そこで、下記のようにReact NativeのTextinputコンポーネントやNative BaseのInputコンポーネントをTextコンポーネントの中で用いようとしましたが、Androidでテストしたところ上手くいきませんでした。
具体的には、インプット部分にあたるところが表示されず、タップしても入力画面になりません。

どのようにすればこういったことが実現できるかご存知の方がいれば、ご回答よろしくお願いします。

```
<View>
  <Text>
    <TextInput width={40}></TextInput>
    <Text>is a knowledge community in which we can ask programming questions and we can answer others’ programming questions.</Text>
  </Text>
</View>

<View>
  <Text>
    <Input width={40}></Input>
    <Text>is a knowledge community in which we can ask programming questions and we can answer others’ programming questions.</Text>
  </Text>
</View>
```

[image: There is no input part in the rendered sentence.]